# Why is OpenSSL crashing?

Tags: c++, c, openssl

Here is the backtrace that I get from gdb:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x040010c2 in ?? () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
#1  0x06822a0b in write () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:82
#2  0x082e6891 in conn_write (b=0x9791b40, in=0xe9125a3 "\027\003\003", inl=175) at bss_conn.c:442
#3  0x082e40cb in BIO_write (b=0x9791b40, in=0xe9125a3, inl=175) at bio_lib.c:247
#4  0x08290991 in ssl3_write_pending (s=0xea22bd8, type=23, 
        buf=0xafdeb08 "Host: graph.facebook.com\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4\r\n", len=146) at s3_pkt.c:881
#5  0x082908a4 in do_ssl3_write (s=0xea22bd8, type=23, 
        buf=0xafdeb08 "Host: graph.facebook.com\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4\r\n", len=146, create_empty_fragment=0) at s3_pkt.c:853
#6  0x08290281 in ssl3_write_bytes (s=0xea22bd8, type=23, buf_=0xafdeb08, len=146) at s3_pkt.c:609
#7  0x0828d0c3 in ssl3_write (s=0xea22bd8, buf=0xafdeb08, len=146) at s3_lib.c:4204
#8  0x082a4eae in SSL_write (s=0xea22bd8, buf=0xafdeb08, num=146) at ssl_lib.c:1002
#9  0x082b363b in ssl_write (b=0xaf5ba48, 
        out=0xafdeb08 "Host: graph.facebook.com\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4\r\n", outl=146) at bio_ssl.c:243
#10 0x082e40cb in BIO_write (b=0xaf5ba48, in=0xafdeb08, inl=146) at bio_lib.c:247
#11 0x0816c7db in SSL_Connection_send (connection=0xaf6ef10, 
        data=0xafdeb08 "Host: graph.facebook.com\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4\r\n", length=146) at Util/SSL_Connection.cpp:318
```

This is the first suspicious valgrind error:

```
==2803== Syscall param write(buf) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==2803==    at 0x6822A0B: ??? (syscall-template.S:82)
==2803==    by 0x82E40CA: BIO_write (bio_lib.c:247)
==2803==    by 0x829790E: ssl23_write_bytes (s23_pkt.c:77)
==2803==    by 0x8296D63: ssl23_client_hello (s23_clnt.c:594)
==2803==    by 0x829621C: ssl23_connect (s23_clnt.c:217)
==2803==    by 0x82A785C: SSL_do_handshake (ssl_lib.c:2564)
==2803==    by 0x82B3C22: ssl_ctrl (bio_ssl.c:423)
==2803==    by 0x82E4552: BIO_ctrl (bio_lib.c:370)
==2803==    by 0x816C2AA: SSL_Connection_connect(SSL_Connection_s*) (SSL_Connection.cpp:162)
==2803==    by 0x8147C17: Connection_connectToHost (Connection.cpp:48)
==2803==    by 0x815E8B7: Http_client_send_prepare(Http_Message_s*) (Http_client.cpp:330)
==2803==    by 0x815E9FD: Http_client_send (Http_client.cpp:357)
==2803==  Address 0xe9e6f33 is 11 bytes inside a block of size 21,848 alloc'd
==2803==    at 0x4028876: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==2803==    by 0x82C898B: default_malloc_ex (mem.c:79)
==2803==    by 0x82C8EAA: CRYPTO_malloc (mem.c:308)
==2803==    by 0x82E349B: BUF_MEM_grow (buffer.c:121)
==2803==    by 0x8296198: ssl23_connect (s23_clnt.c:195)
==2803==    by 0x82A785C: SSL_do_handshake (ssl_lib.c:2564)
==2803==    by 0x82B3C22: ssl_ctrl (bio_ssl.c:423)
==2803==    by 0x82E4552: BIO_ctrl (bio_lib.c:370)
==2803==    by 0x816C2AA: SSL_Connection_connect(SSL_Connection_s*) (SSL_Connection.cpp:162)
==2803==    by 0x8147C17: Connection_connectToHost (Connection.cpp:48)
==2803==    by 0x815E8B7: Http_client_send_prepare(Http_Message_s*) (Http_client.cpp:330)
==2803==    by 0x815E9FD: Http_client_send (Http_client.cpp:357)
```

This is the most recent valgrind error before the crash:

```
== Syscall param write(buf) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==2803==    at 0x6822A0B: ??? (syscall-template.S:82)
==2803==    by 0x82E40CA: BIO_write (bio_lib.c:247)
==2803==    by 0x8290990: ssl3_write_pending (s3_pkt.c:881)
==2803==    by 0x82908A3: do_ssl3_write (s3_pkt.c:853)
==2803==    by 0x8290280: ssl3_write_bytes (s3_pkt.c:609)
==2803==    by 0x828D0C2: ssl3_write (s3_lib.c:4204)
==2803==    by 0x82A4EAD: SSL_write (ssl_lib.c:1002)
==2803==    by 0x82B363A: ssl_write (bio_ssl.c:243)
==2803==    by 0x82E40CA: BIO_write (bio_lib.c:247)
==2803==    by 0x816C7DA: SSL_Connection_send(SSL_Connection_s*, char*, unsigned int) (SSL_Connection.cpp:318)
==2803==    by 0x8147F66: Connection_send (Connection.cpp:167)
==2803==    by 0x815EA67: Http_client_send (Http_client.cpp:368)
==2803==  Address 0xe9125a8 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 17,584 alloc'd
==2803==    at 0x4028876: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==2803==    by 0x82C898B: default_malloc_ex (mem.c:79)
==2803==    by 0x82C8EAA: CRYPTO_malloc (mem.c:308)
==2803==    by 0x8293115: freelist_extract (s3_both.c:708)
==2803==    by 0x8293412: ssl3_setup_write_buffer (s3_both.c:811)
==2803==    by 0x829349B: ssl3_setup_buffers (s3_both.c:829)
==2803==    by 0x82961C3: ssl23_connect (s23_clnt.c:204)
==2803==    by 0x82A785C: SSL_do_handshake (ssl_lib.c:2564)
==2803==    by 0x82B3C22: ssl_ctrl (bio_ssl.c:423)
==2803==    by 0x82E4552: BIO_ctrl (bio_lib.c:370)
==2803==    by 0x816C2AA: SSL_Connection_connect(SSL_Connection_s*) (SSL_Connection.cpp:162)
==2803==    by 0x8147C17: Connection_connectToHost (Connection.cpp:48)
```

With --track-origins:

```
==3588== Syscall param write(buf) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==3588==    at 0x6822A0B: ??? (syscall-template.S:82)
==3588==    by 0x82E40CA: BIO_write (bio_lib.c:247)
==3588==    by 0x829790E: ssl23_write_bytes (s23_pkt.c:77)
==3588==    by 0x8296D63: ssl23_client_hello (s23_clnt.c:594)
==3588==    by 0x829621C: ssl23_connect (s23_clnt.c:217)
==3588==    by 0x82A785C: SSL_do_handshake (ssl_lib.c:2564)
==3588==    by 0x82B3C22: ssl_ctrl (bio_ssl.c:423)
==3588==    by 0x82E4552: BIO_ctrl (bio_lib.c:370)
==3588==    by 0x816C2AA: SSL_Connection_connect(SSL_Connection_s*) (SSL_Connection.cpp:162)
==3588==    by 0x8147C17: Connection_connectToHost (Connection.cpp:48)
==3588==  Address 0x106e8cd3 is 11 bytes inside a block of size 21,848 alloc'd
==3588==    at 0x4028876: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==3588==    by 0x82C898B: default_malloc_ex (mem.c:79)
==3588==    by 0x82C8EAA: CRYPTO_malloc (mem.c:308)
==3588==    by 0x82E349B: BUF_MEM_grow (buffer.c:121)
==3588==    by 0x8296198: ssl23_connect (s23_clnt.c:195)
==3588==    by 0x82A785C: SSL_do_handshake (ssl_lib.c:2564)
==3588==    by 0x82B3C22: ssl_ctrl (bio_ssl.c:423)
==3588==    by 0x82E4552: BIO_ctrl (bio_lib.c:370)
==3588==    by 0x816C2AA: SSL_Connection_connect(SSL_Connection_s*) (SSL_Connection.cpp:162)
==3588==    by 0x8147C17: Connection_connectToHost (Connection.cpp:48)
==3588==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==3588==    at 0x4028876: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==3588==    by 0x82C898B: default_malloc_ex (mem.c:79)
==3588==    by 0x82C8EAA: CRYPTO_malloc (mem.c:308)
==3588==    by 0x83568E7: bnrand (bn_rand.c:134)
==3588==    by 0x8356B6E: BN_rand (bn_rand.c:213)
==3588==    by 0x8356DCD: bn_rand_range (bn_rand.c:281)
==3588==    by 0x8356EA9: BN_rand_range (bn_rand.c:299)
==3588==    by 0x82DE894: EC_KEY_generate_key (ec_key.c:271)
==3588==    by 0x8288A4D: ssl3_send_client_key_exchange (s3_clnt.c:2606)
==3588==    by 0x8283BA6: ssl3_connect (s3_clnt.c:416)
==3588==    by 0x82A4CF2: SSL_connect (ssl_lib.c:949)
==3588==    by 0x82975B7: ssl23_get_server_hello (s23_clnt.c:797)
==3588==    by 0x829624A: ssl23_connect (s23_clnt.c:226)
==3588==    by 0x82A785C: SSL_do_handshake (ssl_lib.c:2564)
==3588==    by 0x82B3C22: ssl_ctrl (bio_ssl.c:423)
==3588==    by 0x82E4552: BIO_ctrl (bio_lib.c:370)
==3588==    by 0x816C2AA: SSL_Connection_connect(SSL_Connection_s*) (SSL_Connection.cpp:162)
==3588==    by 0x8147C17: Connection_connectToHost (Connection.cpp:48)
```

Why is this error happening: these errors look like they are all coming from the OpenSSL library?

Comment: Would be useful to include the exact build of OpenSSL that you are using.

Comment: @MattMcNabb openssl-1.0.1f on ubuntu

Comment: Is the program multi-threaded? If so, did you initialize the static locks?

Comment: @noloader it is, and I initialized both the static and dynamic locks.

Answer (score 2):

From the Valgrind error message it look like your program is trying to access uninitialised or unaddressable values in system call(**write**).

```
==2803== Syscall param write(buf) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==2803==  Address 0xe9125a8 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 17,584 alloc'd
==2803==  Address 0xe9e6f33 is 11 bytes inside a block of size 21,848 alloc'd
```

From the Valgrind[(Memcheck)](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.errormsgs) manual following info can be found regarding this:

> It checks all parameters to system calls.
>
> It checks all the direct parameters themselves, whether they are
>   initialised.
>
> Also, if a system call needs to read from a buffer provided by your
>   program, Memcheck checks that the entire buffer is addressable and its
>   contents are initialised.
>
> Also, if the system call needs to write to a user-supplied buffer,
>   Memcheck checks that the buffer is addressable.
>
> After the system call, Memcheck updates its tracked information to
>   precisely reflect any changes in memory state caused by the system
>   call.

You may want to run your application in Valgrind with **--track-origins=yes** option to get the more detailed information of uninitialized memory uses. You may check out my earlier [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22658693/2724703) on Valgrind and how GDB/Valgrind can be used together to perform the live debugging at the time of first error reported by your program.

Comment: @chacham15: It looks like there is bug/problem in the OpenSSL library and similar bug has been reported. https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=303250

Comment: I found that and used the options they specified to get track-origins to work. I added the `--track-origins` option (see edit), but it appears the memory was allocated and dealt with entire in OpenSSL code.

Comment: OpenSSL pretty much makes Valgrind useless. Some of it is unfortunate (for example, using uninitialized memory for the PRNG. I believe you are seeing them in the `BN_rand`  and friends from your dump), others could be worked around of the dev team cared about the issue (for example, the leak in `ssl_comp_methods`).